# Flatten multiple streams, with events of only of the last stream

Tags: flutter, reactive-programming, reactivex, rxdart

`x` is a stream. On each event, I generate a stream `x_i` that itself spawns events. From this set up, I want to generate a flattened output stream that contains only events of the most recent `x_i`, until `x` ends:

```
x:   ├─┬───┬─────┬────────┤
x_3:   │   │     └─E────H───I─...
x_2:   │   └─B───D────G───────...
x_1:   └─A─────C────F─────────...
```

The expected result is

```
     ├───A───B───D─E────H─┤
```

I can't use [`flatMap`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/flatMap.html) on `x`, because then all `x_i` events would be merged into the output stream, not just those of the most recent sub stream.

I also can't use [`concatMap`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/concatMap.html) because `x_i` are infinite, and the output stream would effectively be `x_1`.

This seems to me like a fairly common scenario, hence my question: Is this possible using standard RxDart (which I'm using), or do I need to implement this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `swtichLatest` operator of rxdart

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html
[image]

Comment: That's what `flatMap` does. I can't use this because then all events from all `x_i` would end up in the output stream, not just the ones from the most recent `x_i`, see "expected result".

Comment: Can't you just pipe your streams to a `take` or `first` ?

Comment: I would not know how: I want to observe all events of `x_i` until an `x_(i+1)` is created. The number of events isn't known upfront.

Comment: Thanks – shouldn't have stopped scrolling when I looked through the docs... Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Also implemented as `switchLatest` in `package:stream_transform` as a `StreamTransformer` rather than requiring a full buy-in to Rx. https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/switchLatest.html